# java - Google Cloud Datastore - Inequality returning "no matching index found"

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, inequality

In **Android Studio**, I'm trying to use **Google Clood Datastore** from an Android app.

With the Google example https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes#Datastore_Indexes_and_properties I am able to add Tom (32 years old) and Lucy (30 years old) as Person and as children of the Company Acme. I can see these two entries are in the datastore in the Google Developers Console.

- I can retrieve children from Company Acme if I set a query filter as below.

  ```
  Key acmeKey = makeKey("Company", "Acme").build();
  makeFilter("__key__",
      PropertyFilter.Operator.HAS_ANCESTOR,
      makeValue(acmeKey)).build()));
  ```

  - If I want to retrieve only Person where age is equal to 32 I add to the filter above  `makeFilter("age", PropertyFilter.Operator.EQUAL, makeValue(32)).build()`
    Then, I get the Person Tom.

---

- But, if, instead of `Operator.EQUAL` I put an inequality filter like `Operator.LESS_THAN` or `Operator.GREATER_THAN` I get the error "**no matching index found**".

---

I think it's a problem of indexes, but I really don't understand how can I set an index. I use Android Studio and I don't use at all the App Engine. I just want to retrieve data as I do with MySQL with a simple `WHERE age > 32`.

Btw, I tried with GQL and I get exactly the exact same problem, work with `EQUAL`, but not with `GREATER_THAN` (and same in https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer).

So, does anybody know how I can fix this problem ? Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Index configuration for Cloud Datastore is handled using the [gcd.sh](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/) tool.

It's easiest if you're able to run your queries against the local datastore provided by `gcd.sh`. The tool can determine exactly which indexes you'll need, and then you can use the `updateindexes` command to configure them on your production app.

If not, you can also configure indexes by hand:

1. `gcd.sh create <project> -d <project>`
2. Create a file at `<project>/WEB-INF/datastore-indexes.xml` with the following content:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<datastore-indexes
  autoGenerate="true">
    <datastore-index kind="Company" ancestor="true">
        <property name="age" direction="asc" />
    </datastore-index>
</datastore-indexes>`

3. `gcd.sh updateindexes <project>`

The exact content of the file will depend on the queries you want to run. [This page](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/indexconfig) gives additional details on the format of the indexes file.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response Ed. I just managed to add an index to my datastore by adding a datastore-indexes.xml file to the WEB-INF folder as you said. And finally it works. I can see now the index under the Google Developers Console and I can retrieve Person where age > 20.

Comment: But I just wonder, why is it so complicate? Why can not we just upload the xml file on the Google Developers Console? It took me over one hour to understand what to do (maybe because of my poor english :-/)

Answer (score 0):

So, as Ed Davisson just said, everything is done with gcd.

It took me a lot of time to understand what to do, so I put my experience below, maybe it will be helpful to someone. I'm working with **Ubuntu**, I don't know about other OS.

1. Download [gcd-v1beta2-rev1-2.1.1.zip](http://storage.googleapis.com/gcd/tools/gcd-v1beta2-rev1-2.1.1.zip) in the **Downloads** folder
2. Unzip the downloaded file
3. In the console, go to the unziped folder `cd Downloads/gcd-v1beta2-rev1-2.1.1`
4. Then, `./gcd.sh create -d myDataset myProjectName` where *myDataset* is the project ID in [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project) (it is composed with 2 random nouns and a number)
5. Go to the unziped folder *gcd-v1beta2-rev1-2.1.1* and you should see a folder **myProjectName**. In this *myProjectName* folder, in the folder *WEB-INF* create a file *datastore-indexes.xml*
6. As I wanted to retrieve *Person* who have the ancestor *Company* and older than 20, I had to add the index as Ed Davisson said

   ```html
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <datastore-indexes autoGenerate="true">
    <datastore-index kind="Person" ancestor="true">
      <property name="age" direction="asc" />
    </datastore-index>
   </datastore-indexes>
   ```
7. In your console, `./gcd.sh updateindexes myProjectName`

Now, in Google Developers Console you can see this new index under *Cloud Datastore -> Index*

And finally you can retrieve *Person where age > 20*

```
Key acmeKey = makeKey("Company", "Acme").build();
Query.Builder query = Query.newBuilder();
query.addKindBuilder().setName("Person");
query.setFilter(makeFilter(

    makeFilter("__key__",
        HAS_ANCESTOR,
        makeValue(acmeKey)).build(),

    makeFilter("age",
        GREATER_THAN,
        makeValue(20)).build()));

 query.addOrder(makeOrder("age", ASCENDING));
```